# Touchscreen stops working after login

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

Running ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a yoga laptop, the touchscreen works perfectly at the log in screen, but when it brings me to the desktop enviroment it stops. this is a completly fresh install with nothing downloaded / added to it. can anybody help me troubleshoot please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo Yoga S1.

I noticed in journalctl -b:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
fwupd[2737]: ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_context.c:69:Esys_Initialize() Initialize default tcti. ErrorCode (0x000a000a)
fwupd[2737]: 21:37:44:0499 FuEngine failed to add udev device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:06CB:7244.0003/>
fwupd[2737]: 21:37:44:0675 FuEngine device 602b0a6cc821d155208724f0e22f8d111542b74c [SAMSUNG MZ7TE128HMGR-000L1] does not define a vendo>
systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
```

I noticed 06CB:7244 is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:7244 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
```

I tried blacklisting plugin synaptics-rmi in /etc/fwupd/daemon.conf:

```
BlacklistPlugins=synaptics-rmi;test;invalid
```

But it did not help. In the end I did:

```
sudo apt remove fwupd
```

It worked, there must be a better way to fix this by tinkering with fwupd though.